# Flutter Dart:HTML querySelector not changing data in index html file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have the following code, I'm trying to update the SEO meta tags on generated data

```
void updateTags() {
    print("run updateTags");
    document.querySelector("meta[name='title']")?.text =
        'testing updating title';

    document.querySelector("meta[name='description']")?.text =
        'Update description testing';

    print(document.querySelector("meta[name='title']")?.text);
    print(document.querySelector("meta[name='description']")?.text);
  }
```

I'm trying to update the Flutter web index.html I can see the updated meta tags but it's not changing the HTML?

I'm calling the function on the build

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setAttribute` method like:

```dart
          document
              .querySelector("meta[name='title']")
              ?.setAttribute("content", 'testing updating title');
```

Comment: I did that it does not work, flutter web renders the index.html